# Google Earth KML Not Properly Rendering Balloon Style

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

This issue has been plaguing me for about 2 days Google isn't helping me figure this one out. Basically, the code below *should* be defining the text within the balloon. Unfortunately, it's not working that way. We're ending up with what seems to be the fallback if GE can't handle the style defined in the KML.

Here's one (of many) ways I've tried injecting the KML straight into the GE plugin for rendering.

```
var kmlString = '' +
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
'<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">' +
'  <Document>' +
'    <Style id="sitegeom">' +
'      <BalloonStyle>' +
'       <text>' +
'           <![CDATA[' +
'           this is<br>a test' +
'           ]]>' +          
'       </text>' +
'      </BalloonStyle>' +
'    </Style>' +
'  </Document>' +
'</kml>';

var kmlObject = $wnd.ge.parseKml(kmlString);
$wnd.ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
```

The code on which this snippet is based came directly from the GE docs. Go figure. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe question not so clear for me, but i think, you need to describe `Placemark` in your KML and define your style in `styleUrl`
Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Style id="sitegeom">
      <BalloonStyle>
       <text>
           <![CDATA[
          this is<br>a test
           ]]>          
       </text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>104.30000001,52.283333343333</coordinates>
        </Point>
        <styleUrl>#sitegeom</styleUrl>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Is it right idea?

Comment: Not quite...the placemarks come from a different KML object entirely, which is created on the fly at a later point in code.

Answer (score 2):

The KML document you're adding later likely can't access the #sitegeom ID you defined at the start in a separate KML document, it's not in-scope.

Try following the Google Earth doc [instructions re: this](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html), by placing the style definition in a separate file:

> If the Style definition is within the same file, precede the Style ID with a # sign. If the Style definition is in an external file, include the complete URL in the  element.

e.g.:

```
<styleUrl>http://www.example.com/path/to/your/style.kml#sitegeom</styleUrl>
```